# Using GPUImage, how would I split image into 4 and apply different filters to all 4 corners and recombine?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I want something similar to the GPU Logo, a different filter on each corner.

[image: GPU Logo]

So far I have managed to achieve this but the image size is half of the original.  Here a simplification of my code:

```
_cropTopLeft = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] 
                initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5)];

CGAffineTransform topLeftTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1, -1);
topLeftTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(topLeftTransform, 0.5, 0.5);
_transformTL = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
_transformTL.affineTransform = topLeftTransform;


// Set up the pipeline: image -> crop -> transform 
//   I don't apply any effects to the corners for now, 
//   just try to recreate the original image

[imageSource addTarget:_cropTopLeft];
[_cropTopLeft addTarget:_transformTL];


// Same with the other corners... TR, BL & BR



// Recombine
// Can only apply 2 inputs to a blend filter, so combine using 3 filteres
// The blend filteres are `GPUImageNormalBlendFilter` instances

[_transformTL addTarget:_blendFilterTop];
[_transformTR addTarget:_blendFilterTop];
[_transformBL addTarget:_blendFilterBottom];
[_transformBR addTarget:_blendFilterBottom];

[_blendFilterTop addTarget:_blendFilterAll];
[_blendFilterBottom addTarget:_blendFilterAll];

[_blendFilterAll addTarget:_myGPUImageView];
```

The issue is that when a corner of the image is cropped, the canvas size is halved.

I believe this half size is then used through the pipeline.

My work around was to half the corner again with the transform, but this results in a 1/2 resolution output image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is, instead of messing with all of the crops and transforms, create a shader that will set the alpha to 0 over the entire image except for the quadrant that you are applying your filter to.

Your filter chain would look like this...

for each quadrant: 
Apply the effect filter -> Apply the set alpha filter -> Do an over blend with the previous pass